# Rearrange data file

Tags: python

I am trying to reorganize a .txt file containing a list of data with traits in the columns and the family on the rows. Basically, I need to write a program that creates rows comparing the people in each family so that the traits persons 1 and 2, 1 and 3, and 2 and 3 are compared. i.e.:

```
A 1 2 7 8 9 10
A 1 3 7 9 9 11
etc.
```

where A is the family, the first 2 numbers are the people compared, the 3rd and 4th numbers are trait1 such as the measurements for each person, and the final numbers are trait2 such as the BMI values for each person.

My input is like this:

```
A 1 trait trait
A 2 trait trait
A 3 trait trait
```

I was able to create a data frame using:

```
data = pandas.read_csv('family.txt.', sep=" ", header = None)
print(data)
```

I cannot seem to figure out an efficient way to concatenate the data into the rows needed above. Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: _where A is the family, the first 2 numbers are the people compared, the 3rd and 4th numbers are trait1 such as the measurements for each person, and the final numbers are trait2 such as the BMI values for each person._

Could you elaborate on what this means? so 3rd value belongs to the first person and 4th belongs to the second person? or are they some diffs?

Comment: @SrinivasSuresh Definetely! Sorry it's a little confusing! so I am trying to compare each relative in the family and their traits to each of their relatives traits. So in the desired output, the columns starting with the two 7's and on are traits where each trait has two numbers(one for each person)

Comment: @H.Minear what? Is it too much trouble to ask for specific inputs with specific outputs? Just using `trait` is *not helpful at all*.

Comment: So the desired output needs to looks something like `A P1 P2 Trait1-P1 Trait1-P2 Trait2-P1 Trait2-P2` ?

Comment: @SrinivasSuresh Exactly!!!!!

Comment: @SrinivasSuresh If you can offer any advice or sample code you would be the best person ever because I am really stuck! Thank you!

Comment: do you prefer an answer that neccesarily uses pandas or did you just use dataframe because its easy to read the csv that way  ?

Comment: @SrinivasSuresh I just used it because it is easier to read-I am open to any answer!

Comment: Ok, I'd suggest just reading the file in one go with read lines, splitting each line with spaces and then grouping them by family. I'm writing a snippet and testing it. which i will post in a few minutes

Comment: @SrinivasSuresh I cannot thank you enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Consider your data was as follows

```
A 1 7 4 5 6
A 2 6 5 4 7
A 3 7 7 5 4
B 1 7 4 5 6
B 2 6 5 4 7
B 3 7 7 5 4
```

Where the first column is the family and the second column is the person_id and all subsequent columns are traits.

Some super dirty and super hastily written code below seems to give you what you want

```
file_lines = []
out_list = []
final_out = []

def read_file():
    global file_lines
    with open("sample.txt", 'r') as fd:
        file_lines = fd.read().splitlines()
    print file_lines

def make_output():
    global file_lines, out_list, final_out
    out_line = []
    for line1 in file_lines:
        for line2 in file_lines:
            line1c = line1.split(" ")
            line2c = line2.split(" ")
            if line1c[0] == line2c[0]:
                if line1c[1] >= line2c[1]:
                    continue
                else:
                    out_list = []
                    out_list.append(line1c[0])
                    out_list.append(line1c[1])
                    out_list.append(line2c[1])
                    for i in range(2, len(line1c)):
                        out_list.append(line1c[i])
                        out_list.append(line2c[i])
                print " ".join(out_list)

read_file()
make_output()
```

The output of print is

```
A 1 2 7 6 4 5 5 4 6 7
A 1 3 7 7 4 7 5 5 6 4
A 2 1 6 7 5 4 4 5 7 6
A 2 3 6 7 5 7 4 5 7 4
A 3 1 7 7 7 4 5 5 4 6
A 3 2 7 6 7 5 5 4 4 7
B 1 2 7 6 4 5 5 4 6 7
B 1 3 7 7 4 7 5 5 6 4
B 2 1 6 7 5 4 4 5 7 6
B 2 3 6 7 5 7 4 5 7 4
B 3 1 7 7 7 4 5 5 4 6
B 3 2 7 6 7 5 5 4 4 7
```

As you can see In family A person 1 is compared with 2 and 3. 2 is compared with 1 and 3 and 3 is compared with 1 and 2.

Obviously there will be duplication because each person is compared with every other person in the family twice.

It's trivial to remove this by maintaining a list of who has been compared with whom.

**P.S:** *I know the script is really dirty but I just wanted to illustrate what i've done. Not write production code*

**EDIT:** *I wanted to write a slightly more complicated duplicate remover. But since the data is so simple a small modification in the continue criterion solved it. the output after this edit is*

```
A 1 2 7 6 4 5 5 4 6 7
A 1 3 7 7 4 7 5 5 6 4
A 2 3 6 7 5 7 4 5 7 4
B 1 2 7 6 4 5 5 4 6 7
B 1 3 7 7 4 7 5 5 6 4
B 2 3 6 7 5 7 4 5 7 4
```

which is free of duplicates

Comment: Thank you again! No worries-I can edit it as well : ) So to remove the duplicates what function would you recommend?

Comment: Well I realized that given your scenario duplicate removal is a bit easier than maintaining a list, so I've edited my code to do this

Comment: I was thinking the same thing! THANK YOU FOR EVERYTHING! Have a nice day!

Comment: No worries, you too